# How can i prove that if some set is a subset of every set in a family of sets, then it is a subset of the intersection of family too.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification, quantifier-elimination

The question is stated as:

Prove: $(\forall B)(B \in F \Rightarrow C \subseteq B) \Rightarrow C \subseteq \bigcap_{A \in F}A$

Thats what i thinked in a textual way: If we assume that for every $B$, if it belongs to $F$ then $C$ is a subset of $B$, we have that all elements from $C$ are in every set of $F$, thus the intersection of $F$ contains at least the elements of $C$, and then $C \subseteq \bigcap F$.

I tried to do something with symbols but i got stucked in the second line:

$$(\forall B)(B \in F \Rightarrow C \subseteq B)$$
$$(\forall B)(B \in F \Rightarrow (\forall x)(x \in C \Rightarrow x \in B))$$
$$(\forall B)(B \notin F \lor (\forall x)(x \notin C \lor x \in B))$$

I dont know how to proceed, so i want to know if the textual part is correct, how this proof should be done and if its possible to do some operation with the quantifiers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that the LHS holds. We want to show the RHS, i.e. if $x\in C$, then $x\in A$ for all $A\in F$.

For this, let us take $x\in C$ an fix some $A\in F$. The LHS now implies that $x\in C\subset A$, so $x\in A$. As this holds for arbitrary $A\in F$, we are done.